# What is the most relevant property for a "release date" for schema type VideoGame

Tags: seo, schema.org

I'm working on some video game sites and have already added a lot of information to the schema data, but the one thing I'm not sure about is how to add a "release date" and was kind of surprised there wasn't a specific property for it when looking here: https://schema.org/VideoGame

The closest one I found was `datePublished`, but the description is "Date of first broadcast/publication." and that doesn't seem totally accurate. There is also `dateCreated`, but to me doesn't necessarily refer to the actual release date.

When searching google for a game, in the knowledge panel it's listed as "Initial release date", but nothing like that exists as a useable property.

What would be the most accurate property to use? Or should I just omit it altogether?

Comment: What issue do you see with "Date of first broadcast/publication"?

Comment: @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions I don't see an issue yet. I was just wondering if there was a more accurate property that I should be using, especially since there are actual publications and similar things leading up to the release.